# ¿Para qué se usa "->" en C y C++ al manejar estructuras de datos?

Tags: c++, c, estructuras-de-datos

¿Para qué se usa `->` en *C*?

Ejemplo: `new -> dato = dato;`.

Código:

```
void insertar(int dato) {
    node *nuevo = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    nuevo -> dato = dato;
    nuevo -> siguiente = primero;
    primero = nuevo;
}
```

Comment: pon tu imagen como texto

Comment: Como te indica @ReneLimon, **no** insertes imágenes; hacen más difícil para otros *replicar* tu código, y tu pregunta prodría ser *bloqueada*.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo tomaré en cuenta no lo sabía

Answer (score 13):

Como sabemos, en C / C++ es habitual trabajar con **punteros**.

En el siguiente código

```
struct Nodo {
  int A;
  int B;
};

struct Nodo *nd = (struct Nodo *)malloc( sizeof( struct Nodo ) );
```

¿ Como accedemos al atributo `A` a través del puntero `nd` ?

Una de las alternativas es:

```
(*nd).A = 10;
```

Sin embaro, C / C++ nos proporcionan un método mas **simple de escribir**, y, personalmente, encuentro que **mas simple de entender**, mediante el operador `->`:

```
nd->A = 10;
```

Ambos métodos son *equivalentes* e intercambiables. `PUNTERO->ATRIBUTO` es un *método abreviado* de hacer `(*PUNTERO).ATRIBUTO`.

`->` es un **operador**, y, por lo tanto, se puede *encadenar*:

```
struct Nodo {
  struct Nodo *n;
  int A;
  int B;
};

ptr->n->A = 10;
```

Comment: Entonces, `->` es el equivalente de `.` cuando de punteros se trata? (sorry por la pregunta).

Comment: @Xam exacto; `->` se usa cuando **la variable de su izquierda** es un puntero.

Answer (score 7):

Se trata de un tipo de [azúcar sintáctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico) para el acceso a miembros de un objeto.

El operador para el acceso a miembros de un objeto es el punto (`.`), así pues: teniendo una instancia de un objeto cualquiera, se accede a un miembro cualquiera del mismo usando el punto:

```
struct Objeto {
    int Miembro;
};

Objeto a, b;
a.Miembro; // <- accede al miembro 'Miembro' de la instancia 'a'.
b.Miembro; // <- accede al miembro 'Miembro' de la instancia 'b'.
```

Si en lugar de una instancia tenemos un puntero a objeto, no podemos usar el operador punto, ya que un puntero no es un objeto. Sería como intentar poner en marcha un coche usando la llave sobre la matrícula: la matrícula no es un coche, aunque nos sirva para identificar un coche en concreto.

Pero si des-referenciamos el puntero con el operador unario de des-referencia (`*`) obtendremos la instancia del objeto y podremos usar el operador punto:

```
struct Objeto {
    int Miembro;
};

Objeto a;
Objeto *b = &a; // el puntero b apunta a la instancia a.
a.Miembro;    // <- accede al miembro 'Miembro' de la instancia 'a'.
(*b).Miembro; // <- des-referencia b y accede al miembro 'Miembro' de la instancia apuntada.
```

Pero la sintaxis `(*puntero).miembro` es incómoda de leer y escribir, así que se decidió usar la sintaxis flecha (`->`) de manera que `puntero->miembro` fuese equivalente a `(*puntero).miembro`. Ambas opciones son usables tanto en C como en C++ pero se aconseja usar el operador flecha (`->`) por ser más claro.

Como curiosidad, quisiera mencionar que el operador flecha (`->`) es sobrecargable en C++ mientras que el operador punto (`.`) no lo es<sup>1</sup>.

Otros azúcares sintácticos de operadores conocidos tanto en C como en C++ serían:

- **Operador de incremento (`++`)**: `variable++` equivaldría a `variable = variable + 1`;
- **Operador de operación-asignación (`+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`)**: `variable += numero` equivaldría a `variable = variable + numero`.
- **Operador de indexación (`[]`)**: `arreglo[indice]` equivaldría a `*(arreglo + indice)`

Existen otros azúcares sintácticos no relacionados con operadores, pero mencionarlos todos sería alargar innecesariamente la respuesta.

---

<sup>1</sup>Permitir la sobrecarga del operador punto (`.`) fue propuesto por Bjarne Stroustrup y Gabriel Dos Reis para el estándar C++17 ([documento técnico N4173](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4173.pdf)) pero la propuesta ha sido pospuesta para más adelante.

Answer (score 4):

`->` se utiliza para acceder a los elementos de una estructura de datos que se tiene referenciada por un puntero o *"pointer"*.

`node *nuevo = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));`

Crea una variable del tipo puntero a `node` i le asigna la dirección que devuelve `malloc()` con el espacio necesario para un `node`.

`nuevo->dato = dato;`

Accede al elemento `dato` de `node` y le asigna el valor de `dato` que ha sido pasado como argumento de la función.

Answer (score 3):

En lenguaje C, el operador **`->`** se utiliza después de una variable de tipo puntero que apunta a una estructura de datos, para indicar a qué campo de la estructura queremos acceder.

En este caso, la variable ***dato*** es un puntero que apunta a una variable de tipo ***node***, que tiene varios campos dentro (dato, siguiente, ...) y con

```
nuevo -> dato
```

se indica que accedemos a su campo *dato*.