# duda matrices c++

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio en el que me piden comparar un valor con los numeros de una matriz dada una precisión que no se puede superar, los numeros que cumplan esa condición se imprimirán en una nueva matriz y si no la cumplen, se imprimirá un 0.

Yo lo he intentado hacer, este es la función que me dan en el archivo cabecera: previamente, declaré una variable global con la precisión

```
const double epsilon=1e-3;

void filtra(matrix_t& M, matrix_item_t it, double precision);
```

Bien, en el hpp la desarrollo, y he puesto esto:

```
void matrix_t::filtra(const matrix_t& M, matrix_item_t it, double epsilon) {

redimensiona(m_,n_); //destruí la matriz A y la redimensioné asignándole un número de filas y columnas
 matrix_t E; //esta matriz la declará para que guarde los números de la matriz A que cumplan con la precisión,y los que no cumplan, que guarde un 0 en su posición en mi nueva matriz,al usar funciones booleanas

for (i=0; i<(E.get_m()); i++) {
    for (j=0; j<(E.get_n());j++)
        if ((E.get_matrix_item(i,j))-matrix_item_t it < epsilon){
            E.set_matrix_item(i,j);
       }
```

`M` es un array dinámico que contiene las filas y las columnas de la matriz `A`, la matriz original `matrix_item_t` it es el elemento que tengo que buscar en la matriz `A`.

Luego en el `main`, puse esto:

```
matrix_t A;

    matrix_t &B=matrix_t A;
    matrix_t &E=matrix_t B;

cout << endl;
A.read(cin);
cout << "---  MATRIZ ORIGINAL  ---" << endl;

B.write();

cout << "---  PRECISIÓN 0.001  ---" << endl;
A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-3);

cout << "---  PRECISIÓN 0.001  ---" << endl;

A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-3);
B.write();

B.write();

cout << "---  PRECISIÓN 0.01   ---" << endl;

B.write();

cout << "---  PRECISIÓN 0.1    ---" << endl;
A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-1);
B.write();
cout << "---  PRECISIÓN 1.0    ---" << endl;
A.filtra(B,5.254,1.0);
B.write();
```

Esta última parte me la daban en el ejercicio como código que tenía que poner en el main, la de A.filtra...

la que puse yo es la de `matrix_t &B=matrix_t A;` `matrix_t &E=matrix_t B;` hasta que empieza `A.filtra`, y obviamente todo lo del cpp y hpp lo hice yo, el problema es que cuando compilo me salen muchos errores, y a mí me cuesta mucho entender los errores que señala el compilador:

```
main_m_3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main_m_3.cpp:25:18: error: redeclaration of ‘matrix_t A’
         matrix_t A;
                  ^
main_m_3.cpp:5:11: note: ‘matrix_t A’ previously declared here
  matrix_t A;
       ^
main_m_3.cpp:26:18: error: conflicting declaration ‘matrix_t B’
         matrix_t B;
                  ^
main_m_3.cpp:12:18: note: previous declaration as ‘const matrix_t& B’
  const matrix_t& B=A;
              ^
main_m_3.cpp:27:21: error: conversion from ‘const matrix_t*’ to non-scalar type ‘matrix_t’ requested
         matrix_t E=&B;
                 ^
main_m_3.cpp:35:3: error: ‘class matrix_t’ has no member named ‘filtra’
 A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-4);
   ^
main_m_3.cpp:39:3: error: ‘class matrix_t’ has no member named ‘filtra’
 A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-3);
   ^
main_m_3.cpp:43:3: error: ‘class matrix_t’ has no member named ‘filtra’
 A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-2);
   ^
main_m_3.cpp:47:3: error: ‘class matrix_t’ has no member named ‘filtra’
 A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-1);
  ^
main_m_3.cpp:51:3: error: ‘class matrix_t’ has no member named ‘filtra’
 A.filtra(B,5.254,1.0);
   ^

no ‘void matrix_t::filtra(const matrix_t&, matrix_item_t, double)’ member function declared in class ‘matrix_t’
 void matrix_t::filtra(const matrix_t& M, matrix_item_t it, double epsilon)
```

La verdad que no sé dónde falla el código, se agradece muchísimo ayuda

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te agradeceríamos que pusieses el código completo. Hay errores que no se corresponden con tu código...

Answer (score 1):

Para corregir los errores debes empezar con el primer error que te muestra y buscar corregirlo. Como no se muestra todo el main.cpp es dificil saber donde esta exactamente pero tu si lo puedes encontrar.

```
main_m_3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main_m_3.cpp:25:18: error: redeclaration of ‘matrix_t A’
         matrix_t A;
```

este error te indica que dentro del "int main()" en la linea 25, especificamente en la columna 18 tu re-declaras la variable matrix_t A y yo creo que es en las siguientes lineas donde esta el error

```
matrix_t A;

    matrix_t &B=matrix_t A;
    matrix_t &E=matrix_t B;
```

porque la declaras arriba y la redeclaras abajo, lo correcto sería

```
matrix_t A;

    matrix_t &B= A;
    matrix_t &E= B;
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

> A mí me cuesta mucho entender los errores que señala el compilador

En ese caso, creo que puede ser buena idea que te ayudemos a entenderlos para que puedas corregirlos más adelante.

---

El primer error que muestras:

```
main_m_3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main_m_3.cpp:25:18: error: redeclaration of ‘matrix_t A’
     matrix_t A;
              ^
main_m_3.cpp:5:11: note: ‘matrix_t A’ previously declared here
     matrix_t A;
```

Consiste en una re-declaración de variables (`redeclaration of ‘matrix_t A’`). Esto significa que en un punto del código declaraste una variable llamada `A` de tipo `matrix_t` y en otro punto del mismo código declaraste otra variable llamada `A`.

En concreto, el compilador te indica que en la línea 5, columna 11 declaraste `A` por primera vez y en la línea 25 columna 8 la declaraste por segunda vez. En C++ una declaración tiene el siguiente formato:

```
tipo nombre;
tipo nombre = inicializador;
tipo nombre(parámetros de construcción);
tipo nombre{parámetros de construcción};
```

El lenguaje C++ (y muchos otros) prohíbe explícitamente usar los nombres de entidades (objetos, funciones) más de una vez porque si varias cosas (entidades) tienen el mismo nombre ¿a cuál de ellas te refieres cuando usas dicho nombre?

Si revisamos tu código vemos lo siguiente:

```
matrix_t A;

    matrix_t &B=matrix_t A;
    matrix_t &E=matrix_t B;
```

Declaras el objeto `A` de tipo `matrix_t`, a continuación declaras una referencia (`&`) a `matrix_t` llamada `B` y usas como inicializador **otra declaración**: `matrix_t A`. La considera otra declaración porque sigue el formato que hemos visto antes. Cuando declaras la referencia a `matrix_t` llamada `E` te sucede lo mismo pues intentas inicializar `E` con una declaración (cosa que no está permitida), dicha declaración es del objeto llamado `B` (que ya habías intentado declarar en la línea anterior). Así que, cambia el código a lo siguiente:

```
matrix_t A;
matrix_t &B = A;
matrix_t &E = B;
```

Omitiendo el tipo, el compilador se dará cuenta que no estás re-declarando `A` o `B`.

Tu siguiente error no parece tener correspondencia con el código que has mostrado:

```
main_m_3.cpp:26:18: error: conflicting declaration ‘matrix_t B’
     matrix_t B;
              ^
main_m_3.cpp:12:18: note: previous declaration as ‘const matrix_t& B’
  const matrix_t& B=A;
```

Indica que en la línea 26 columna 18 estás declarando una entidad de nombre `B` cuando otra entidad con el mismo nombre ya se declaró en la línea 12 columna 18. Si sigues las recomendaciones de las líneas anteriores deberías ser capaz de corregir el error.

A continuación te muestra el error:

```
main_m_3.cpp:27:21: error: conversion from ‘const matrix_t*’ to non-scalar type ‘matrix_t’ requested
     matrix_t E=&B;
```

En este error, el compilador te está indicando que intentas guardar en un objeto de tipo puntero constante a `matrix_t` (`‘const matrix_t*’`) un objeto de tipo `matrix_t` y esto requiere una conversión de tipos que no sabe cómo realizar.

Se debe a que has antepuesto el [et (`&`)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26) al nombre de una variable de tipo `matrix_t`, el et (`&`) obtiene la dirección de memoria de una variable y devuelve un puntero a dicha variable (puedes leer más detalles [en esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46909/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-int-e-int/46931#46931)). Si esto es correcto o incorrecto dependerá de lo que quisieras hacer, cosa que no podemos saber con el código que has compartido.

Los errores posteriores:

```
main_m_3.cpp:35:3: error: ‘class matrix_t’ has no member named ‘filtra’
 A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-4);
main_m_3.cpp:39:3: error: ‘class matrix_t’ has no member named ‘filtra’
 A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-3);
main_m_3.cpp:43:3: error: ‘class matrix_t’ has no member named ‘filtra’
 A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-2);
main_m_3.cpp:47:3: error: ‘class matrix_t’ has no member named ‘filtra’
 A.filtra(B,5.254,1E-1);
main_m_3.cpp:51:3: error: ‘class matrix_t’ has no member named ‘filtra’
 A.filtra(B,5.254,1.0);

no ‘void matrix_t::filtra(const matrix_t&, matrix_item_t, double)’ member function declared in class ‘matrix_t’
 void matrix_t::filtra(const matrix_t& M, matrix_item_t it, double epsilon)
```

Te están indicando que la clase `matrix_t` no dispone de un miembro llamado `filtra`. El error sucede porque le estás pidiendo a un objeto de tipo `matrix_t` (llamado `A`) que use una función llamada `filtra` que debería pertenecer al mismo y no pertenece, puedes ver más detalles en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46015/para-qu%c3%a9-se-usa-en-c-y-c-al-manejar-estructuras-de-datos/46083#46083).

Según puedo ver, la función `filtra` es libre (no pertenece a ningún objeto) y espera recibir como primer parámetro un valor de tipo `matrix_t`, así que asumo que el uso esperado de esta función sería:

```
filtra(B, 5.254, 1E-4);
filtra(B, 5.254, 1E-3);
filtra(B, 5.254, 1E-2);
filtra(B, 5.254, 1E-1);
filtra(B, 5.254, 1.0);
```

Pero no puedo estar seguro, ya que el segundo parámetro es de tipo `matrix_item_t` y no veo ninguna declaración de ese tipo.

Comment: Es lo que le dije en el comentario... en el código expuesto falta información relevante