# error: request for member "siguiente" is something not a structure or union

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct nodo *siguiente;
};

typedef struct nodo NODO;
typedef NODO *NODOSIG;

void f1(NODOSIG *lista);
void f2(NODOSIG **lista, NODOSIG *nuevo);

int main()
{
    NODOSIG LISTA = NULL;

    f1(&LISTA);

    return 0;
}

void f1(NODOSIG *lista)
{
    NODOSIG NUEVO;
    int x;
    NUEVO = malloc(sizeof(NODO));

    if(NUEVO != NULL){
        printf("\n\tIngrese un numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        NUEVO->dato = x;
        NUEVO->siguiente = NULL;

        f2(&lista, &NUEVO);
    }
}

void f2(NODOSIG **lista, NODOSIG *nuevo)
{
    lista->siguiente = *lista;
    *lista = nuevo;
}
```

Buenas, tengo este pedazo de código en el cual busco en la función 1 crear un nodo y en la función 2 (anidada a 1) encadenarlo por el principio, sé que se puede hacer todo en una función pero quiero hacerlo así porque dependiendo de el dato es sí, se va a encadenar al principio o al final (existencia de una función 3), el problema es que como en el título dice marca error en la siguiente linea de la función 2:

```
nuevo->siguiente = *lista;
```

Comment: El problema es la redefinición de tipos que luego te hace confundirte. Si `NODOSIG` ya es un puntero a un `NODO`, en el prototipo de `f2` tienes `NODOSIG ** lista`, lo que termina siendo `NODO *** lista`. Realmente confuso. De ahí que no te deje hacer `lista->siguiente = nuevo`, porque lista no es un puntero a `NODO`, sino un puntero a un puntero a un puntero a `NODO`. Casi nada!!!! Todo esto, obviando el final de tu pregunta, que haces referencia a algo que no está en el código. Entiendo que el error de compilación te da donde te he dicho.

Comment: Perdón, tenía un error en el código, ya lo corregí, ahora si aparece esa linea de error.

Answer (score 2):

Tu código es propenso a errores por el uso desaconsejado de alias de tipos. El primer alias:

```
typedef struct nodo NODO;
```

Hace que el tipo `struct nodo` reciba el alias de `NODO`. El segundo alias:

```
typedef NODO *NODOSIG;
```

Hace que el tipo `NODO *` (que es `struct nodo *`, puntero a la estructura `nodo`) reciba el alias de `NODOSIG`. Este tipo de nomenclatura se considera mala práctica porque ocultas un puntero (`*`) en un nombre de tipo que no incorpora el puntero. Por eso, en el cuerpo de `f2`:

```
void f2(NODOSIG **lista, NODOSIG *nuevo)
{
    lista->siguiente = *lista;
    *lista = nuevo;
}
```

Cuando recibes un puntero a puntero a `NODOSIG`, dado que `NODOSIG` es `NODO *` que a su vez es `struct nodo *` entonces estás recibiendo un puntero a un puntero a un puntero a la estructura `nodo`, por lo tanto la función `f2` anterior y la siguiente son exactamente la misma:

```
void f2(struct nodo ***lista, struct nodo **nuevo)
//                  ^^^                   ^^
//                    \                     \__ puntero a puntero a estructura nodo
//                     \
//                      \__ puntero a puntero a puntero a estructura nodo
{
    lista->siguiente = *lista;
    *lista = nuevo;
}
```

Dado que [el operador flecha (`->`) es un azúcar sintáctico para `(*objeto).miembro`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46083/2742), al escribir `lista->siguiente` estamos ejecutando la siguiente orden:

```
(*lista).siguiente = *lista;
```

Dado que `lista` es un *puntero a puntero a puntero a estructura nodo* entonces `*lista` es un *puntero a puntero a estructura nodo* y como tal, carece de miembros ya que sigue estando a dos indirecciones de tenerlos:

```
                                                  NODOSIG **
                                                    /
                                   NODOSIG * <-----/
                                     /  
     NODO             NODOSIG <-----/
+-------------+         /
| struct nodo | <------/
+-------------+
|    dato     |
|  siguiente  |
+-------------+
```

Mi consejo es que dejes de usar alias de tipos… y si los usas, no lo hagas ocultando punteros.

Comment: ya logré que funcionara pero no utilicé lo que me comentaste, redefiní mi f2 de la siguiente forma `void f2(NODOSIG **lista, NODOSIG nuevo) `y utilicé como dices un doble operador de indirección a lista, y ya funciona todo bien, solo me falta entender el por que funciona ; . ;

Comment: Me alegro que encontrases solución, pero mi consejo sigue siendo que dejes de usar alias de tipos… y si los usas, no lo hagas ocultando punteros ya que  se considera mala práctica porque ocultas un puntero (`*`) en un nombre de tipo que no incorpora el puntero, fomentando que aparezcan errores como el que has tenido.