# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a una clase lista que está como atributo de otra clase?

Tags: c++

Tengo una clase Grafo en la cual cada vértice tiene una atributo una lista que debería contener las aristas ordenadas.

Pero en la función que quiero acceder para insertar la primera arista, me da un problema de segmentación creo. Y no lo puedo solucionar.

Este es la clase del `Vertice`:

```
class Vertice {
    Vertice *siguiente;
    Vertice *anterior;
    Arista *adyacente;
    ListaAristas *listaAristas; // **** ERROR *************
    string palabra;
    float poder;
    int cantidadAristas;
    int totalPesosAristas;

    //public:
    friend class Grafo;
};
```

Y estos son las clases que se utilizan para la lista:

```
class Node {        //Este nodo es para guardar los datos de la lista de arsitas.
    string palabraDestino;
    int distacia;
    Node *siguiente;
    Node *anterior;

    friend class ListaAristas;
    friend class Grafo;
};


class ListaAristas {
    Node *punteroPrincipalListaAristas;
    public:
        void inicializarPunteroLista();
        void mostrarListaAristas(ListaAristas lista);

    friend class Vertice;
    friend class Grafo;
 };
```

El error está en esta función, específicamente en la líneas que se intenta
acceder al `punteroPrincipalListaAristas`, ese puntero es para acceder a esa lista y recorrerla.

El código del error:

```
void Grafo::insertarNodoListaAristas(Vertice *inicio, Vertice *final, int distancia){
    inicio->listaAristas->punteroPrincipalListaAristas = NULL;
    Node *nuevaPalabraDestino = new Node;
    Node *auxiliarLista;
    Node *elDeAdelante; //POSIBLEMENTE ESTÉ DE MÁS:
    Node *elDeAtras;

    nuevaPalabraDestino->palabraDestino = final->palabra;
    nuevaPalabraDestino->distacia = distancia;
    nuevaPalabraDestino->anterior = NULL;
    nuevaPalabraDestino->siguiente = NULL;

    if(inicio->listaAristas == NULL){
        inicio->listaAristas->punteroPrincipalListaAristas = nuevaPalabraDestino;
    }

    else{
        elDeAdelante = inicio->listaAristas->punteroPrincipalListaAristas->siguiente;
        elDeAtras = inicio->listaAristas->punteroPrincipalListaAristas->anterior;
        auxiliarLista = inicio->listaAristas->punteroPrincipalListaAristas;
        while(auxiliarLista != NULL){
            if(nuevaPalabraDestino->distacia < auxiliarLista->distacia){
                nuevaPalabraDestino->siguiente = auxiliarLista;
                auxiliarLista->anterior = nuevaPalabraDestino;
                nuevaPalabraDestino->anterior = elDeAtras;      //   7->   4 5 7 8 
                break;
            }
            auxiliarLista = auxiliarLista->siguiente;
        }
        if(nuevaPalabraDestino->anterior == NULL){
            inicio->listaAristas->punteroPrincipalListaAristas = nuevaPalabraDestino;
            }
    }
}
```

El debugger de GDB menciona este error en esa asignación mencionada, "Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acceder a un dato que está como atributo de otro, simplemente usa los operadores de acceso, punto (`.`) para objetos y flecha (`->`) para punteros.

Pero ese no es tu problema ni es tu pregunta (aunque lo hayas puesto como título). Tu problema es que pasas un puntero posiblemente nulo a una función y lo primero que haces con el es des-referenciarlo:

```
void Grafo::insertarNodoListaAristas(Vertice *inicio, Vertice *final, int distancia){
    inicio->listaAristas->punteroPrincipalListaAristas = NULL;
//  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  |       |             |
//  |       |             |_<--- Des-referencias 'listaAristas' hasta 'punteroPrincipalListaAristas'
//  |       |_<--- Des-referencias 'inicio' hasta 'listaAristas'
//  |_ <--- Recibes puntero 'inicio'

    Node *nuevaPalabraDestino = new Node;
    Node *auxiliarLista;
    Node *elDeAdelante; //POSIBLEMENTE ESTÉ DE MÁS:
    Node *elDeAtras;

    nuevaPalabraDestino->palabraDestino = final->palabra;
    nuevaPalabraDestino->distacia = distancia;
    nuevaPalabraDestino->anterior = NULL;
    nuevaPalabraDestino->siguiente = NULL;

    if(inicio->listaAristas == NULL){
    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Miras si 'listaAristas' pudiera ser NULL, pero ya lo habías
    usado en la primera línea de la función como si NO FUESE NULL */
        inicio->listaAristas->punteroPrincipalListaAristas = nuevaPalabraDestino;
    }

    // ...
    // ...
}
```

[El operador flecha es un azúcar sintáctico de `(*objeto).miembro`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46083/2742), así que cuando usas la flecha sobre un objeto primero des-referencias el puntero y luego accedes al miembro. Des-referenciar un puntero nulo puede dar lugar a [violación de acceso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso), que es lo que describes.