# ¿Cómo acceder al metodo de un objeto usando un puntero doble en C++?

Tags: c++, poo, punteros

Tengo un puntero doble que apunta a un puntero que a su vez apunta a un objeto. Con el puntero puedo acceder a los métodos del objeto pero con el puntero doble no. Hay manera de hacerlo o se tiene que usar referencias?

Este es un código que lo ejemplifica:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "objeto.h"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Objeto **puntD,*dir_obj, n("mesa","madera");

    dir_obj= &n;
    cout<<dir_obj->getNombre()<<endl; //getNombre devuelve un string
    puntD = &dir_obj;
    cout<<puntD->getNombre()<<endl; //Marca error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debes hacerlo de esta forma: `(*puntD)->getNombre()`

Comment: Me sirvió, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador flecha es un [azúcar sintáctico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46083/2742) de una desreferencia de puntero y un acceso a miembro. Por lo tanto, estas dos instrucciones son equivalentes:

```
dir_obj->getNombre();
```

```
(*dir_obj).getNombre();
```

Cuando tenemos un doble puntero, la flecha actúa igual:

```
puntD->getNombre();
```

Equivale a:

```
(*puntD).getNombre();
```

Dado que `puntD` es un doble puntero (`Objeto **`), desreferenciarlo una vez nos quita sólo un puntero, el cuál no dispone de la función miembro `.getNombre()` porque no es un objeto, puedes probar desreferenciando dos veces:

```
(**puntD).getNombre();
```