# Error en c++, field has incomplete type (strucs)

Tags: c++, struct

Hola estoy empezando en c++ hace un tiempo ahora estoy haciendo strucs y me sale el error field inv has incomplete type 'inventario', no se cual es el error, la idea sera que la linea mario.inv.espada funcionara i no se porque pero me da error en struct inventario inv aqui el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct hero
{
    string name;
    int  life;
    int velocidad;
    int posx;
    int posy;
    struct inventario inv;
};

struct inventario
{
    bool espada;
    string escudo;
    string arco;
    int num_manzanas;


};



int main()
{

    struct hero mario;

    mario.name = "Mario Bros";
    mario.life = 100;
    mario.velocidad = 50;
    mario.posx = 0;
    mario.posy = 0;
    mario.inv.espada = true;
}`
```

Comment: El problema de tu código es el orden de declaración, solo debes declarar primero la estructura Inventario y después la estructura Hero. Esto sucede por la dependencia y el orden lineal que tiene este lenguaje.

Comment: Graciass me ha funcionado, no hacia falta el typedef solo era el orden de struct

Answer (score 3):

En C++ los objetos pueden ser declarados, definidos o instanciados:

- **Declaración**: Se indica que el objeto existe sin detallar cómo es; el nombre del objeto podrá usarse siempre que no provoque la creación de una instancia. En otras palabras, nos describe el objeto sin entrar en detalles:

[image]

- **Definición**: Se describe el objeto detalle, cuenta como declaración si no había declaración previa, puede instanciarse el objeto sin limitaciones. Es decir, nos detalla el objeto al completo:

[image]

- **Instanciación**: Cuando se crea el objeto. En otras palabras, crea lo que corresponda con las características indicadas:

[image]

---

En tu objeto `hero` tienes una declaración del objeto `inventario`:

```
struct hero
{
    string name;
    int  life;
    int velocidad;
    int posx;
    int posy;
    struct inventario inv;
    /*     ^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Declaro que 'inventario' existe,
                          pero no entro en detalles de lo que es. */
};
```

Esto no es un problema, porque puedes declarar objetos y definirlos más tarde, el problema es que los objetos no definidos no pueden ser instanciados; y tú estás instanciando:

```
struct hero
{
    string name;
    int  life;
    int velocidad;
    int posx;
    int posy;
    struct inventario inv;
    //                ^^^ <-- 'inv' es una instancia de 'inventario'
};
```

El compilador no tiene ni idea de los detalles de `inventario`, así que no puede incluirlo en `hero`.

Puedes solucionar el problema de las siguientes maneras:

- Cambiando el orden de definición. Si cuando instancias `hero`, el tipo `inventario` ya está definido, el problema desaparece:

  ```
    struct inventario
    {
        bool espada;
        string escudo;
        string arco;
        int num_manzanas;
    };

    struct hero
    {
        string name;
        int  life;
        int velocidad;
        int posx;
        int posy;
        inventario inv;
    };
  ```
- Haciendo que el objeto `inventario` sea un puntero. Los punteros no cuentan como instancias de objetos, pero a la hora de instanciar el objeto que apuntes a través del puntero el objeto tiene que estar definido. Recuerda que en este caso, tendrás que acceder a los objetos del inventario con [flecha (`->`) no con punto (`.`)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46083/2742).

  ```
    struct hero
    {
        string name;
        int  life;
        int velocidad;
        int posx;
        int posy;
        inventario *inv;
    /*  ^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Declaro que 'inventario' existe,
                       pero no entro en detalles de lo que es. */
    };

    struct inventario
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Defino 'inventario' completamente.
    {
        bool espada;
        string escudo;
        string arco;
        int num_manzanas;
    };

    int main()
    {
        // Creo una instancia de 'inventario'.
        inventario inventario_mario;
        // Creo una instancia de 'hero'.
        hero mario;

        // Asocio la instancia de 'hero' con la instancia de 'inventario'.
        mario.inv = &inventario_mario;

        return 0;
    }
  ```
- Haciendo que el objeto `inventario` sea una referencia. Las referencias no cuentan como instancias de objetos pero no pueden construirse sin que apunten a nada, así que tendrás que proveer una instancia de `inventario` para crear un `hero`:

  ```
    struct inventario;
    /*     ^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Declaro que 'inventario' existe,
                          pero no entro en detalles de lo que es. */

    struct hero
    {
        hero(inventario &i) : inv{i} {}
    /*                   ^        ^ <-- Proveemos una instncia de 'inventario'
                                        en el constructor y la guardamos en 'inv'. */
        string name;
        int  life;
        int velocidad;
        int posx;
        int posy;
        inventario &inv;
    };

    struct inventario
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Defino 'inventario' completamente.
    {
        bool espada;
        string escudo;
        string arco;
        int num_manzanas;
    };

    int main()
    {
        // Creo una instancia de 'inventario'.
        inventario inventario_mario;
        // Creo una instancia de 'hero' y le asocio la instancia de 'inventario'.
        hero mario(inventario_mario);

        return 0;
    }
  ```
- Haciendo que `inventario` sea un tipo anidado de 'hero'. Dado que están tan íntimamente ligados, no hay motivo para que estén separados:

  ```
    struct hero
    {
        string name;
        int  life;
        int velocidad;
        int posx;
        int posy;

        struct inventario
    //         ^^^^^^^^^^ el tipo 'inventario' forma parte del tipo 'hero'.
        {
            bool espada;
            string escudo;
            string arco;
            int num_manzanas;
        } inv;
    //    ^^^ <-- Instancia de 'inventario'
    };
  ```

---

Por cierto, en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) las `struct` son tipos de primer orden, no necesitan un `typedef` para ser usadas.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez el orden tenga algo que ver y el typedef, prueba a hacerlo de este modo a ver si consigues evitar el error:

```
typedef struct inventario
{
    bool espada;
    string escudo;
    string arco;
    int num_manzanas;
};

typedef struct hero
{
    string name;
    int  life;
    int velocidad;
    int posx;
    int posy;
    inventario inv;
};



int main()
{

    hero mario;

    mario.name = "Mario Bros";
    mario.life = 100;
    mario.velocidad = 50;
    mario.posx = 0;
    mario.posy = 0;
    mario.inv.espada = true;
}
```

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con el `typedef`.