# ¿Por qué esta función llamada "crearNodo" es de tipo puntero?

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo arboles binarios de búsqueda (ABB). **Esta es la función que no entiendo:**

```
nodo *crearNodo(int valor){

    nodo *nuevo_nodo = new nodo(); 
    
    nuevo_nodo->dato = valor;

    nuevo_nodo->derecha = NULL;

    nuevo_nodo->izquierda = NULL;
    
    return nuevo_nodo;
}
```

**Siendo** más específico, lo que quiero es que me traten de **explicar** es ¿Cómo **funciona** esa función y además **por qué** esa función es de tipo puntero?. Gracias a quien me haya **quitado** mi duda. *PD: esto es de C++.*

Comment: Gracias Gabitohh, no sabia como poner el codigo de una manera mas entendible, te lo agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Cómo **funciona** esa función y además **por qué** esa función es de tipo puntero?

La función no es de tipo puntero, la función es de tipo `nodo *(int)`.

---

El tipo `nodo *(int)` es una función que devuelve un puntero a `nodo` (`nodo *`) y recibe un entero (`int`), todas estas funciones comparten el mismo tipo:

```
nodo *crearNodo(int valor);
nodo *patatas_Fritas_con_Ketchup_y_mayonesa(int valor);
nodo *f(int valor);
nodo *cn(int valor);
```

Respecto a cómo funciona, estos son los detalles:

1. `nodo *nuevo_nodo = new nodo();` crea un objeto `nodo` en memoria dinámica (mediante el operador `new`). Para crear dicho objeto se ha usado su constructor por defecto (es decir: el constructor que no recibe parámetros), la memoria que ocupa ese nuevo objeto está apuntada por el puntero `nuevo_nodo`.
2. `nuevo_nodo->dato = valor;` se asignan datos al sub-objeto `dato` del objeto `nodo` (en notación C++ sería `nodo::dato`), dado que se asigna a través de un puntero (`nuevo_nodo`) es necesario usar el operador flecha (`->`)<sup>1</sup>.
3. `nuevo_nodo->derecha = NULL;` se asignan datos al sub-objeto `derecha` del objeto `nodo` (en notación C++ sería `nodo::derecha`), dado que se asigna a través de un puntero (`nuevo_nodo`) es necesario usar el operador flecha (`->`)<sup>1</sup>, el sub-objeto `nodo::derecha` seguramente será otro puntero a nodo (`nodo *`) y se le asigna el resultado de desplegar la macro `NULL` para indicar que ese puntero no apunta a nada.
4. `nuevo_nodo->izquierda = NULL;` se asignan datos al sub-objeto `izquierda` del objeto `nodo` (en notación C++ sería `nodo::izquierda`), dado que se asigna a través de un puntero (`nuevo_nodo`) es necesario usar el operador flecha (`->`)<sup>1</sup>, el sub-objeto `nodo::izquierda` seguramente será otro puntero a nodo (`nodo *`) y se le asigna el resultado de desplegar la macro `NULL` para indicar que ese puntero no apunta a nada.
5. `return nuevo_nodo;` envía fuera de la función la dirección de memoria dinámica almacenada en `nuevo_nodo` que ahora está apuntando a un objeto `nodo` cuyos sub-objetos `nodo::dato`, `nodo::izquierda` y `nodo::derecha` han sido inicializadas.

Ahora, vamos a la parte seria:

> *PD: esto es de C++.*

Esto sería C++ si estuviéramos en el año 1985<sup>2</sup>, hace décadas que un código así se considera obsoleto, propenso a errores, innecesariamente largo y repleto de malas prácticas.

### Retorno de la función.

Para empezar, está enérgicamente desaconsejado devolver punteros desde funciones, más aún si este puntero apunta a memoria dinámica, supón los siguientes usos de la función `crearNodo`:

```
crearNodo(0);
crearNodo(1) = NULL;

if (es_martes())
{
    nodo *trece = crearNodo(13);
}
```

En el primer caso el puntero devuelto se pierde, generando una [fuga de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria). En el segundo caso el puntero devuelto es sobrescrito por otro valor (dando lugar a otra fuga de memoria) para después ser descartado. En el tercer caso el puntero devuelto se guarda en una variable, pero no se borra el puntero antes de que la variable salga de ámbito, generando otra fuga de memoria más.

En C++11 se añadieron al lenguaje los atributos, y en C++17 se añadió el atributo `[[nodiscard]]`, que permite declarar objetos y retornos de función como datos que no deben descartarse:

```
[[nodiscard]] nodo *crearNodo(int valor);
```

Cambiando la función para usar atributos, evitaremos el primer caso de fuga de memoria, pero no evitaremos el segundo o tercero, es imposible evitar que nuestro código sea usado por idiotas<sup>3</sup> pero podemos esforzarnos para que nuestro código sea inocuo incluso cuando se usa mal. Si cambiamos el puntero en crudo por un puntero inteligente:

```
std::unique_ptr<nodo> crearNodo(int valor);
```

Evitaremos las fugas de memoria incluso en el segundo y tercer caso.

### ¡Usa constructores o inicialización uniforme!

Suponiendo que el objeto `nodo` tenga este aspecto:

```
struct nodo {
    int valor;
    nodo *izquierda, *derecha;
};
```

Podemos hacer que la creación e inicialización del nodo sea en una sola línea:

```
nodo *nuevo_nodo = new nodo{valor, NULL, NULL}; 

return nuevo_nodo;
```

Si inicializamos los sub-objetos donde son declarados, el código puede acortarse más:

```
struct nodo {
    int valor;
    nodo *izquierda = NULL, *derecha = NULL;
};

nodo *crearNodo(int valor){

    nodo *nuevo_nodo = new nodo{valor}; 
    
    return nuevo_nodo;

}
```

Es más, ni siquiera necesitamos la variable temporal:

```
nodo *crearNodo(int valor){ 
    
    return new nodo{valor};

}
```

Llegados a este punto, me pregunto incluso ¿para qué queremos la función `crearNodo`?, si usamos un puntero inteligente ya tenemos una función para crear un `nodo`:

```
std::unique_ptr<nodo> n = std::make_unique<nodo>(valor);
```

### No uses `NULL`, usa `nullptr`.

La macro `NULL` se traduce (dependiendo de implementación) en `0` o en `(void*)0`, esto se debe a que los enteros son implícitamente convertibles a punteros:

```
int *i = 0; // 0 es un entero ¡no un  puntero!
void f(int *puntero){}

f(0); // 0 es un entero ¡no un puntero!
```

Esto puede provocar problemas:

```
void f(int *puntero){}
void f(int valor){}

f(NULL); // Llamada ambigua ¿llamas a la versión puntero o a la versión entero?
```

Para evitar esto se creó el literal de puntero nulo `nullptr`:

```
void f(int *puntero){}
void f(int valor){}

f(0);       // Llama a la versión entero
f(nullptr); // Llama a la versión puntero
```

### En resumen

Tu `nodo` debería tener este aspecto:

```
struct nodo {
    int valor;
    nodo *izquierda = nullptr, *derecha = nullptr;
};
```

Y la función `crearNodo` no debería siquiera existir, usa punteros inteligentes y llama a `std::make_unique`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Lee [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46083/2742) para saber más del operador flecha.

<sup>2</sup>[C++ nació *oficialmente* en 1983](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/que-es-cpp11-historia-de-cpp/).

<sup>3</sup>Programar hoy día es una carrera entre los ingenieros de software esforzándose por crear mayores y mejores programas a prueba de idiotas, y el universo intentando crear mayores y mejores idiotas. Por el momento, el universo va ganando
—Douglas Adams—

Comment: Gracias por esta respuesta, alucino lo que ha cambiado C++, muy bien explicado.

Comment: @ordago ¿Por qué has borrado tu respuesta?

Comment: Porque mi respuesta no aporta nada que no aporte ya esta respuesta.

Comment: @ordago eso quiere decir que no aporta menos, ergo es útil.

Comment: Gracias por explicarme bro, te lo agradezco. Por cierto estoy aprendiendo de Programación ATS, pero a veces no explica muy bien.